# reduce 2 same data of dropdown list in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

My code use 2 same value of dropdown list  of Product : in html and javascript.

When i edit my product data, need double update in 2 place.

[image]

In html:

```
<td ><select name="product_text" id="new_product">
    <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>
    <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>
    <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>
    </select> 
     </td>
```

In Javascript

```
product.innerHTML='<select id="product_text'+no+'">\
                    <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>\
                    <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>\
                    <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>\
                    </select>' ;
```

How can i use function in javascript to reduce display dropdown database again in javascript?

My code link: https://jsfiddle.net/bvotcode/b6wj85dt/21/

HTML

```
    <meta name="Table dropdown number va date" content="dropdown number va date">

<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ><select name="product_text" id="new_product">
    <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>
    <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>
    <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>
    </select> 
     </td>
<td><input type="number" id="new_quantity"></td>
<td><input type="date" id="new_date"></td>
     
<td><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function edit_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="block";
        
 var product=document.getElementById("product_row"+no);
 var quantity=document.getElementById("quantity_row"+no);
 var date=document.getElementById("date_row"+no);
        
 var product_data=product.innerHTML;
 var quantity_data=quantity.innerHTML;
 var date_data=date.innerHTML;
        

   product.innerHTML='<select id="product_text'+no+'">\
                    <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>\
                    <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>\
                    <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>\
                    </select>' ;
 document.getElementById("product_text"+no).value = product_data;   
 quantity.innerHTML="<input type='number' id='quantity_text"+no+"' value='"+quantity_data+"'>";
 date.innerHTML="<input type='date' id='date_text"+no+"' value='"+date_data+"'>";
}

function save_row(no)
{
 var product_val=document.getElementById("product_text"+no).value;
  
 var quantity_val=document.getElementById("quantity_text"+no).value;
 var date_val=document.getElementById("date_text"+no).value;

 document.getElementById("product_row"+no).innerHTML=product_val;
 document.getElementById("quantity_row"+no).innerHTML=quantity_val;
 document.getElementById("date_row"+no).innerHTML=date_val;

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="none";
}

function delete_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
}

function add_row()
{
 var new_product=document.getElementById("new_product").value;
 var new_quantity=document.getElementById("new_quantity").value;
 var new_date=document.getElementById("new_date").value;
        
 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='product_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_product+"</td><td id='quantity_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_quantity+"</td><td id='date_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_date+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_product").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_quantity").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_date").value="";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, consider posting this over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get an extensive review of your code, because there is a lot that could be done better. Two suggestions for now:

1. Avoid hard coding HTML inside your JS (this question is a first good step)
2. There is normally no need to give everything a unique ID. Instead you usually can reference everything in relation to each other, possibly with help of classes. For example, the edit/save/delete buttons can look up which table row their in to find the elements they needs.

In this specific case you could clone the existing select from the HTML:

```
val productText = document.getElementById("product_text").cloneNode();

// Change the ID
productText.id = "product_text" + no;

// Set the value
productText.value = product_data;

// Clear the parent
// (There are better ways to empty an element, but I'm just using this for now)
product.innerHTML = ""; 

// Insert the cloned element
product.appendChild(productText);
```